# Requesting an inexistent image generating self coded 404 error page instead of webserver response

Tags: webserver, http-status-code-404

Existent file. http://us.battle.net/d3/static/images/layout/site-bg/body-bg-1680px.jpg

Nonexistent file. http://us.battle.net/d3/static/images/layout/site-bg/body-bg-2500px.jpg

Normally, web server should give an error like: "Not found. The requested document was not found on this server."

However, trying to reach a missing image loads Battle.net's own 404 page.

How do they handle it? .htaccess? front controllers? custom webserver configuration?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the webserver being used.  In apache there are configuration options to set custom paths for error responses including 404, e.g.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /somewhere/customMessage.html
ErrorDocument 500 /somewhere/differentMessage.html
```

So that would go in the apache config or you could put it in .htaccess.